# My Azure service bus receiver closes due to Idle Timeout and I haven't found a way to fix it

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, inversion-of-control, azureservicebus

I have a pretty basic .NET 6 app which only goal is to receive messages from Azure Service Bus and handle them. When my app works, I am pretty happy with the result and it is answering the business logic I expect.

The thing is, after listening to a message and handling it, my Azure service bus receiver  goes iddle and the link is closed.

Here are some logs from my deployed app (it is a docker image deployed on AKS through jenkins/argocd for information) :

```
info: Inventory_Create_Worker.API.Consumer.CreateInventoryConsumerService[0]

      Message received and handled: {"Title":"inventory creation event","Description":"Extract from excel file","Event":":CONFIDENTIAL_INVENTORY_DATA"}

info:  Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus[38]

      Receive Link Closed. Identifier: queue-inventory-creation-dev-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx, 
      SessionId: , linkException: Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus.ServiceBusException: The link 'amqps://personaldevservicebus-development.servicebus.windows.net/-f1a43db3;0:5:6:source(address:/queue-inventory-creation-dev,filter:[])'
      is force detached. Code: aggregate-link1318524517. Details: AmqpMessagePartitioningEntityMessageCache.IdleTimerExpired: Idle timeout in Seconds: 900. (GeneralError).
      For troubleshooting information, see https://aka.ms/azsdk/net/servicebus/exceptions/troubleshoot..
```

Here is how I inject into my ioc IAzureClientFactory :

```
            services.AddAzureClients(clientsBuilder =>
            {
                clientsBuilder.AddServiceBusClient(connectionString:azureQueueConfig.ConnectionString)
                    .WithName(ConfirmationCreateServiceBusClientName)
                    .ConfigureOptions(options =>
                    {
                        options.RetryOptions.Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
                        options.RetryOptions.MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
                        options.ConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                        options.RetryOptions.MaxRetries = 5;
                    });
            });
```

At first I didn't have any .ConfigureOptions and I feel like my issue is probably  inside it.

Here is my background service which consumes messages from Azure Service bus :

```
using Shared;
using Shared.AzureServiceBus;
using Shared.Interfaces;
using Shared.Interfaces.Infrastructure;
using Shared.Interfaces.Provider;
using Shared.Interfaces.Service;
using Shared.Models.Config;
using Shared.RabbitMq;
using Shared.Services;
using Inventory_Create_Worker.Application.Common.Interfaces.Authentication;
using Inventory_Create_Worker.Infrastructure.Authentication;
using Inventory_Create_Worker.Shared.Constants;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using static Inventory_Create_Worker.Shared.Constants.AzureConstant;


    public class CreateInventoryConsumerService : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<CreateInventoryConsumerService> _logger;
        private ServiceBusReceiver _serviceBusReceiver;
        private ServiceBusClient _serviceBusClient;
        private readonly IAzureClientFactory<ServiceBusClient> _azureClientFactory;
        private readonly AzureQueueConfig _azureQueueConfig;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

        public CreateInventoryConsumerService(IAzureClientFactory<ServiceBusClient> serviceBusClientFactory,
            ILogger<CreateInventoryConsumerService> logger,
            IOptions<AzureQueueConfig> azureQueueOptions, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
            _azureClientFactory = serviceBusClientFactory;
            _azureQueueConfig = azureQueueOptions.Value;
            _serviceBusClient = _azureClientFactory.CreateClient(name: AzureConstant.InventoryCreateServiceBusClientName);
            _serviceBusReceiver = _serviceBusClient.CreateReceiver(queueName: _azureQueueConfig.QueueName);
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            try
            {
                var receivedMessage = await _serviceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessageAsync(cancellationToken: stoppingToken);
                if (receivedMessage != null)
                {
                    using (var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope())
                    {
                        var serviceProvider = scope.ServiceProvider;
                        var mediator = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMediator>();
                        Console.WriteLine("BEGINNING TO CONSUME SERVICE");

                        var createInventoryEvent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedMessage.Body);
                        Console.WriteLine("var createInventoryEvent = Encoding.UTF8.GetString DONE");

                        CreateInventoryFromEventCommand command = new(createInventoryEvent);
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            "CreateInventoryFromEventCommand command = new(createInventoryEvent); DONE");

                        await mediator.Send(command, stoppingToken);
                        Console.WriteLine("_mediator.Send(command) DONE");

                        _logger.LogInformation("Message received and handled: " + createInventoryEvent);
                        Console.WriteLine("Message received and handled: " + createInventoryEvent);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Message could not be executed in Inventory_Create_Worker.CreateInventoryConsumerService.ExecuteAsync, Exception raised: {ex.Message} )");
                Console.WriteLine($"Message could not be executed in Inventory_Create_Worker.CreateInventoryConsumerService.ExecuteAsync, Exception raised: {ex.Message}");
                RecreateServiceBusInstances();
            }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// When our service bus crashes, we need to recreate it.
        /// If not we are not listening to Azure Service bus events anymore and our Inventory consumer service is not guaranteed anymore
        /// </summary>
        private void RecreateServiceBusInstances()
        {
            try
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("Recreating a new ServiceBusReceiver and a new  ServiceBusClient instance");
                Console.WriteLine("Recreating a new ServiceBusReceiver and a new ServiceBusClient instance");
                _serviceBusClient =
                    _azureClientFactory.CreateClient(name: AzureConstant.InventoryCreateServiceBusClientName);
                _serviceBusReceiver = _serviceBusClient.CreateReceiver(queueName: _azureQueueConfig.QueueName);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError($"Failed to recreate ServiceBus instances: {ex.Message}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Failed to recreate ServiceBus instances: {ex.Message}");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does it actually stop processing your messages though?

Comment: @DavidG it seems so because before receiving a message, I get new logs about the azure bus receiver still waiting every 5 mins, and once it says it's closed all logs end.


Also, I just tested by publishing a new message to the azure queue and nothing happened.

Comment: Idle timeouts do not stop the client from working.  The receiver will recreate connections/links on demand when you call `ReceiveMessageAsync`.   If you're not seeing your logs written, then it would seem that either ExecuteAsync is no longer being called, the cancellation token is set, there are no messages returned by Service Bus, or the logger has issues.   I'd suggest capturing a 10-minute slice of Azure SDK logs (https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/azure/sdk/logging) and then opening an issue in the Azure SDK repository for assistance (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues).

Comment: @JesseSquire Hi Jesse, I am sorry for the late answer. I thank you very much for your detailed message, my team will look into it. I think its probably ExecuteAsync no longer being called.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @DavidG, @Jesse Squire for your inputs.

Your `CreateInventoryConsumerService` looks good, and it's designed to handle messages from Azure Service Bus using a background service in a .NET application.

```cs
var receivedMessage = await _serviceBusReceiver.ReceiveMessageAsync(cancellationToken: stoppingToken);
```

- Here we need to check that `stoppingToken` passed to `ReceiveMessageAsync` is effectively linked to the cancellation token of the `BackgroundService`.

Here I have updated configuration to set the `ConnectionIdleTimeout` to a longer duration.

```cs
services.AddAzureClients(clientsBuilder =>
{
    clientsBuilder.AddServiceBusClient(connectionString: azureQueueConfig.ConnectionString)
        .WithName(ConfirmationCreateServiceBusClientName)
        .ConfigureOptions(options =>
        {
            options.RetryOptions.Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
            options.RetryOptions.MaxDelay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);
            options.ConnectionIdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15); // Set a longer idle timeout
            options.RetryOptions.MaxRetries = 5;
        });
});
```

[image]

*Received messages:*
[image]
[image]

**Azure ServiceBus:**

[image]